# MultiSelect date picker using typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to implement multiselect date picker using ngb and tyepscript. Can someone plz help me with coding using Angular 4? 
I want to convert this jquery to typescript.

```
$('.date').datepicker({
    multidate: true,
    format: 'dd'
});
```

Comment: I need one like this: https://codepen.io/ranjith555/pen/OyKjjm?editors=1111

Comment: please use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pick-datetime

Comment: But in this multiselect date picker is not there, I can't select multiple dates at a time.

Comment: Like this, I want one : codepen.io/ranjith555/pen/OyKjjm?editors=1111

Comment: you can check the demo of date range

Comment: @ChaitraR please have a look on my answer and if you have issues let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

**index.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https:////maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

**component.ts** declare outside component class.

```
declare var jquery:any;
declare var $ :any;

ngOnInit(){
    // need to add it inside timeout because jquery takes little time to load
    setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log("came");
      $('.date').datepicker({
        multidate: true,
      format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
      });
    },3000);
  }
```

**component.html**

```
<div class="container">
    <h3>Bootstrap Multi Select Date Picker</h3>
    <input type="text" class="form-control date" placeholder="Pick the multiple dates">
</div>
```

That's all.

[Working Demo](https://angular-multi-select-date.stackblitz.io/)

I hope this will help you to use jquery with typescript as you wanted. If you have any issues or doubts let me know.

Comment: I think it is not a good way to add jquery library in angular project.

Comment: I answered as per the question asked. I don't know the requirement of the questioner. but there are lots of ways we can use jquery with typescript as my one.

Comment: Hi Suvethan, Thanks for the response. Can you plz tell me how can we implement the same without using jquery?

Comment: Suvethan / Vikram , Can you plz help me with this?? https://stackoverflow.com/q/50019212/9568759

Answer (score 0):

Just look at [this](http://arca-computing.github.io/MultipleDatePicker/). It has many other options

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link, it is providing to choose multiple date selection,
you only need to allow "Allow Multiple Selection" options

https://vlio20.github.io/angular-datepicker/

[image: DatePicker image]

Thanks